# javascript enabled button does not post correct in IE

Tags: javascript, perl, internet-explorer, cgi

I'm experiencing issues with IE9 which is not performing the actions I need when clicking a button that was initially disabled, and re-enabled via javascript.

I have a form (built with perl CGI) which has several buttons. These are all disabled in the actual html, and are being enabled when the form is completely loaded. This is done to avoid users saving the page before it is fully loaded.

In all browsers the buttons appear disabled initially, and get enabled when the page is fully loaded. Also in IE. 
Now these re-enabled buttons don't do their work when clicked in IE (tested with IE 9), but they do work as expected in firefox and chrome.

The code for one of these buttons as it appears in the IE developer tools:

```
<input name="Event_Action" id="syncStream" type="submit" value="Create Sync Stream"/>
```

The code which creates the button initially disabled:

```
 print $query->submit( -name=>'Event_Action', -value=>$btnCreateSyncStream, -disabled=>'disabled', -id=>'syncStream');
```

The buttons are being enabled via the onload event of the body tag:

```
<body onload="enableButtons()">
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/pdf/pdf.pl?&amp;pdf_id=1071&amp;release=at7.1.0&amp;pdf_patch_rel_phase=b" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return validatePatchNr()" name="MYFORM">
```

The javascript function enableButtons:

```
function enableButtons()
{
  var buttons = document.getElementsByName("Event_Action");
  for (i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
  {
    buttons[i].disabled=false;
  }  
}
```

Now, when one of these re-enabled buttons is being used, IE seems to reload the page, but the actual action linked to the button is not being executed. 
The same page in Chrome and Firefox works correctly. Both of these browsers execute the correct action.

I supsect that not every field on the form is being submitted which causes the Perl script not to recognize the action that is requested, but I'm not sure of that yet.

I tried debugging the issue with the dev tools in IE, but those are not really easy to work with if you're used to firebug.

Anyone has any idea what might be going wrong here? I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Hit F12, network, capture and see what the browser sends

Comment: If you "suspect" that the problem is in the Perl script that receives the form, you should test that.  Print the fields you receive to the log, and see if you received them all.

Comment: Might be cache issue, IE is known for aggressive cache. Try to clear the cache and see if this "solve" the problem.

Comment: dan1111, I suspect IE for not sending all fields to the perl script. Not the perl script. As I just mentioned in one of the comments below, this is an existing script which is already used for several years. Only recently the buttons are created disabled and re-enabled by the javascript. This was done to avoid a saving bug when users are pressing the buttons before the page is fully loaded.
If I re-enable the buttons in the initial HTML the page completely works as expected, so something in the javascript re-enabling is causing this issue in IE only.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the tip. This was indeed what i was looking for. I'm trying to debug the posts that IE does now. The first few tests seem to reveal that sometimes the parameter 'Event_Action' is more than once in the post. That can be the cause of the issue. Will get back if I had a change to decently test this suspicion.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: tried this several times before, and on different systems, but to no avail. Thanks for thinking with me though.

Comment: @TiWu well, if you have additional form element (text, hidden, radio etc) named "Event_Action" the browser will also send its value, separated with comma. Make sure you don't have such element or creating it elsewhere.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That is indeed what I am trying now. I found that there is one button on the form (not a submit button with 'input type=submit', but an actual 'button' tag) which only calls a popup form, but this is also being submitted in the POST when using any of the other buttons.
I'm setting up a debug version of the script now to test out this suspicion.

Comment: Hmm.. IE does indeed send values of `<button>`s (while other browsers don't send) as far as I remember so this might explain things.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: this solved my issue indeed. I removed the name attribute from the <button> tag, and targeted that specific button via the ID in my enableButtons function. Now all major browsers work as expected. Thanks again for your input! Can I mark a comment as answer? If not, can you please answer this question so I can credit you for your help?

Comment: Glad it's sorted, actually [Sumit's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13914333/447356) is based on the same idea so it will be fair to accept it maybe adding comment saying how you fixed the issue there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well did you try to use different name of each button ? Usually some browser do not submit name value pair of each button, but some browser does. I Guess you should change the name of each button to be unique and use a hidden field to determine the Action to perform rather than button VALUE.

Comment: I am sure the names are not the cause of the issue. This app is some legacy code that is already used for more than 5 years.
The only changes that were recently done is making the buttons disabled untill the page is fully loaded. The names of the buttons have not been changed.

Comment: I'm marking this as answer, because I eventually found that a <button> tag with the same name attribute and value 'Event_Action' was the root cause of my issue. Apparently IE also posts <button> tags while the other browser don't. I would also like to thank mplungjan and ShadowWizard for their comments which lead me to the solution.